# How generate array of weeks

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need generate array of weeks, with empty days before and after.

```
[ //month
 ['','','',1,2,3,4] //week
 ...
 [25,26,27,28,29,30,'']
]
```

Comment: try using `moment.js` and show us once you try and fail

Comment: [Here's some `moment.js` helpers for you](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/529).

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Why do I need a library? This is a simple function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I did

```
const generateMonth = (date) => {
  const getLocalDay = (date) => {
    let day = date.getDay();

    if (day == 0) { 
      day = 7;
    }
    return day;
  };

  const currentMonth = date.getMonth();
  const firstDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), currentMonth, 1);
  const lastDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), currentMonth + 1, 0);
  let month = [];
  let week = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < getLocalDay(firstDate); i++) {
    week.push('');
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= lastDate.getDate(); i++) {
    const tmpDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), currentMonth, i);
    if (getLocalDay(tmpDate) == 1) {
      if (week.length) month.push(week);
      week = [];
    }
    week.push(i);
  }

  for (let i = getLocalDay(lastDate); i < 7; i++) {
    week.push('');
  }

  if (week.length) month.push(week);

  return month;
};
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIPIe.png)